use springboot webclient send get request , query string contain {} , failed
use springboot webclient send get request , query string contain {} , faild
    String url = "http://localhost:8080";
    String query = "sum(avg_over_time(request_cnt{topic_name=\"topic_name_one\"}[5m]))";
    url = url + "?query="+query;
    WebClient.create()
            .get()
            .uri(url)
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToMono(String.class).subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));

 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'topic_name="topic_name_one"'
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:370)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$QueryUriTemplateVariables.getValue(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.lambda$expandQueryParams$5(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:456)

if UriComponentsBuilder build query
String encodedQueryParam = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(query)
        .build()
        .encode()
        .toUriString();
        then uri(url = url + "?query="+encodedQueryParam) 

Causing secondary encoding
